# Problem installing package upgrade "QuickAction - no QuickAction named SendEmail found"

Tags: managed-package, quickaction, unmanaged-package, lightning-quickaction, global-actions

The failing version of the package added a `Global-Xyz Layout.layout-meta.xml` file that starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <quickActionList>
        <quickActionListItems>
            <quickActionName>SendEmail</quickActionName>
        </quickActionListItems>
        ...
```

and the package upgrade fails with:

> (Global-Xyz Layout) In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named
> SendEmail found

Running:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m quickAction:SendEmail
```

in the org does return markup hard to understand why there is an error.

Anyone know what the problem is and if there is a workaround?

Comment: Is that a sandbox with email deliverability disabled?

Comment: Thanks @kurunve, My colleague will check.

Comment: Hi @kurunve, From my colleague: "it is a dev org and it says All Emails for Email Deliverability".

Comment: Hi @KeithC were you able to resolve it? I get this failure also when trying to install the package

Comment: Hi @Json, No, we took it out of the package.